# CakePHP Coding Guidelines: Why are some properties camelCased instead of CamelCased?

Tags: php, cakephp, coding-style

Just a quick question:

When looking to [Controller.php](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php):

What's the underlying coding convention for property-names? I always thought, that properties, which reference a object starts with a uppercase letter, whereas basic properties, referencing booleans/strings/ints, starts with a lowercase letter.

But, in Controller.php, there are:

`public $request; // referencing an instance of a CakeRequest object
public $View; // referencing an instance of a View`

So, where's the difference?

Comment: personal preference or someone deviating from the coding style spec being used by the rest of the project.

Comment: Java unwritten coding rules(object oriented) state that classes and class referances are CamelCased while methods, objects and object references are camelCased. And that is where the concept comes from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general rule regarding [variable and property casing is](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/contributing/cakephp-coding-conventions.html#variables):

> Normal variables should start with a lowercase letter, and should be written in camelBack in case of multiple words. Variables containing objects should start with a capital letter

As such your understanding is correct.

There are however some inconsistencies for/from:

- Backwards-compatibility
- Multiple developers, some more consistent than others
- Mistakes =)

Answer (score 1):

The reason they differ is changing opinion over time I guess. When CakePHP had relatively few objects internally it made sense to call them out with CamelCase names. However, over time we've added more objects, and in some cases like `request` wanted to avoid potential issues with userland code that may make `Request`. On top of these is the need to not break compatibility needlessly.

My current thinking is that framework internal objects, or non-userland objects will be camelBacked, while userland objects like Tables, Components, Tasks, Helpers etc are CamelCased.

Comment: This sure helps to avoid collisions with `$this->request` vs `$this->Request` (Some Component or Model maybe) inside a Controller scope.